# Recover directories changed into files

Tags: data-recovery

So, I was running a command on my `/var/www/html` directory, and it seems everything somehow got changed into files. I'm not sure what went wrong, but is there any way I can recover everything? It appears that all the directories appear as files with the same name and such. I remember using a program called `freedups` on the directory, which hard links duplicate files together, but I'm not sure if that's what caused this error to happen.

Output of `ls -al`

```
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ascii
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? corgi
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? default.html
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dnld
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? downloads
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? games
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? games_beta
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .htaccess
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? index.html
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls -la /var/www/html` so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: Yes in Linux everything is a file. What command did you run and what were you expecting to find?

Comment: @ByteCommander updated the question

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /var/www/html`?

Comment: I can't see how the `d` part at beginning makes you think it is plain file

Comment: @rancho - a directory is a file - https://opensource.com/life/15/9/everything-is-a-file and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141016/a-laymans-explanation-for-everything-is-a-file-what-differs-from-windows

Comment: There are 3 types of files: plain files, directory files, special files, https://www.linux.com/blog/file-types-linuxunix-explained-detail

Comment: I used the word "plain" and my comment was to OP

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you lost execution permissions on your `/var/www/html` directory, at least for your current user.

On directories, the execution permission bit determines whether you have permission to `stat` its contents, i.e. to retrieve information about the files and subdirectories inside it.

Simply add the execution bit for everybody on that directory and it should be fine again:

```
sudo chmod +x /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an `ls -al` on the `"file"`

If that works then you may have a chance of recovery

Next try: `chmod 700 "file"`

at that point you may need to drop your session (log out) and go back in with a new session

... and take heart everything in Unix is basically a "file" your directories are just more so.